# Download image from URL using php code?

Tags: php, image, url

How can I use php to download an image from URL (eg: https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png) then save it?
This is what I came up with so far, it gives me an error in 'file_put_contents' function.

```
<form method="post" action="">
<textarea name="text" cols="60" rows="10">
</textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" class="button" value="submit" />
</form>

<?php
    $img = "no image";
    if (isset($_POST['text']))
    {
    $content = file_get_contents($_POST['text']);
    $img_path = '/images/';
    file_put_contents($img_path, $content);    
    $img = "<img src=\"".$img_path."\"/>";
    }
    echo $img;
?>
```

It gives me the error:

`[function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\img.php`

The `/images/` directory is located in the same directory of the php file and is writable.

Comment: 4 answers in 1min!! Hope your problems are quickly solved.

Comment: you have never accepted any answer? Kindly upvote and accept the answers that helped you.

Comment: @Rohit ok found out how to accept :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You cannot save the image with your existing code because you do not provide a file name. You need to do something like:

```
$filenameIn  = $_POST['text'];
$filenameOut = __DIR__ . '/images/' . basename($_POST['text']);

$contentOrFalseOnFailure   = file_get_contents($filenameIn);
$byteCountOrFalseOnFailure = file_put_contents($filenameOut, $contentOrFalseOnFailure);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I already used `file_get_contents` in the code. It works fine but I cant save the image.

Comment: @Sarah: My bad, I misread the code. Edited the answer in the meanwhile.

Comment: This is the error I get:
`[function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\img.php on line 14`

Comment: @Sarah: Does the directory `/images/` exist? Is it writable by your web server? Basic debugging.

Comment: it exists in the same directory where the php file is, and it is writable.

Comment: @Sarah: Then `/images/` does not exist, but `./images/` exists. I edited the answer to match.

Comment: Warning to anyone coming across this later! don't just accept a file and assume its an image - it could be a php script, and then all the visitor has to do is run the PHP just uploaded and own your server.

Answer (score 1):

`file_put_contents()` requires first parameter to be file name not the path.

Answer (score 1):

What is your error ? But you have the right way to do what you want to do.

Just take care in your code, I can see `file_put_contents($img_path,` but `$img_path` is a path to a folder.
You need to write something like :

**example**

```
$img_path="home/downloads/my_images";
file_put_contents($img_path."/flower.jpg");
```

Comment: Thanks for replying!
So I need to specify the image name in the code?

Comment: Yes, you could use your $_POST['text'] but be aware of bad contents. You need to sanitize your $_POST and then work on it to get the name of the image. Look at [basename](http://ca3.php.net/manual/fr/function.basename.php) it can maybe helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
file_put_contents($img_path, $content);
```

To what are you putting to?? i think you have made a mistake with `get` and `put`. or missed to specify the full path including the file name and extension

Answer (score 0):

I added one condition to accepted answer to check the image type as follows,

```
 if (exif_imagetype($_POST['text']) == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
     $filename = './images/'.basename($_POST['text']);
     file_put_contents($filename, $content);
 }
```

from above example I show how to check png images before download the files and for more content types you can find [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) .