# how to get values using simple html parser or something else

Tags: javascript, php, html, simple-html-dom

This may be possibly duplicate.
but I want to know that how can I get text from a paragraph using simple HTML DOM Parser or something else which have a more button (perhaps prefferably called a link) at the end of paragraph.
e.g
`This is test string and I want to get this data but don't know how to
[more...]`

and the actual text is 
`This is test string and I want to get this data but don't know how to get it
Please anybody help me.`

So anyone who could explain how can I get this complete paragraph.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need to check some text that you know you want to search or do you generally need to search for a text that you don't know? In any case, I'm pretty sure you need to use http://us2.php.net/preg_match regexp.

Comment: i want to get about GE paragraph and some more companies like that

Comment: http://www.linkedin.com/company/1015?trk=vsrp_companies_res_name&trkInfo=VSRPsearchId%3A2646459271384809644652%2CVSRPtargetId%3A1015%2CVSRPcmpt%3Aprimary#

Comment: @ mcuadros . I'm currently getting other fileds using PHP, so I don't know it is a js Q or not(PHP doing this smoothly to get other sections)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the source code of this web page is reformatted and rearranged using JavaScript, and since *Simple HTML DOM* doesnt handle JS, you must work on the raw code (before JS alterations) wich you can check using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>... Then, based on it, you write your parser correctly...

He're a working code answering your question:

```
// includes Simple HTML DOM Parser
include "simple_html_dom.php";

$url = 'http://www.linkedin.com/company/1015?trk=vsrp_companies_res_name&trkInfo=VSRPsearchId%3A2646459271384809644652%2CVSRPtargetId%3A1015%2CVSRPcmpt%3Aprimary#';

//Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html->load_file($url);

// Get the node having "text-logo" class
$div = $html->find('div.text-logo', 0);

echo $div;
echo "<hr>";

// Get logo node
$logo = $html->find('img.logo', 0);

echo $logo->alt ." => ". $logo->src;

// Clear dom object
$html->clear(); 
unset($html);
```

[`Working DEMO`](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/a6i-vph)

Comment: @ Enissay : can you please tell me that how could i get the logo name and also logo from the same address thanks

Comment: :) thanks man..this will give me logo src but can you provide me an example that how could I grab image and store it on local machine??

Comment: It would be easy since you have the image's url... You'll find a plenty of answers here and on google... If you fails, feel free to start a new question so we don't overload this one :)

Comment: ok thanks again. BUt currently I'm facing this problem that failed to open stream functon file_put_contents() :(

Comment: Did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801471/download-image-from-url-using-php-code